# If $A$ and $B$ commute, show that they have a common eigenvector?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

That is, if $AB = BA$. I can see that it is true if all the eigenvalues of $A$ or $B$ are distinct. Let $(\lambda, \textbf{x})$ be an eigenpair of $A$ (or whichever one has distinct eigenvalues). So

\begin{align*}
A\textbf{x} = \lambda \textbf{x} \\
BA\textbf{x} = \lambda B \textbf{x} \\
AB\textbf{x} = \lambda B \textbf{x}
\end{align*}

So either $(\lambda, B\textbf{x})$ is an eigenpair of $A$ or $B\textbf{x} = \textbf{0}$ and then $(0, \textbf{x})$ is an eigenapair of $B$. If the first is the case, $B\textbf{x}$ must be a multiple of $\textbf{x}$ as $\lambda$ already has an eigenvector associated with it and it can have no more.

In fact, if $A$ or $B$ has all distinct eigenvalues then it seems they must have exactly the same eigenvectors. I'm not sure how to get the result I actually want though.

Edit:
The family of commuting matrices sharing an eigenvector definitely encompasses this result, but the tools used their are beyond what we've developed in the course I'm taking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $n\times n$ matrix $A$ we can find an eigenvalue $\lambda$ (although we may have to use complex numbers). Then there is an eigenspace $E_\lambda$ of vectors of dimension $0<m\leq n$ corresponding to $\lambda$. Choose a basis $\mathcal{B}=\{\textbf{x}_1,\dotsc,\textbf{x}_m\}$ for this eigenspace, and consider how the matrix $B$ acts on those basis vectors, which gives you a new representation $B'$ of (the restriction of ) $B$ relative to this basis.

$$B'=B|_{E_\lambda}=\begin{pmatrix}
B\textbf{x}_1 & \dotsc & B\textbf{x}_m
\end{pmatrix}$$

A priori, since there are $m$ vectors with $n$ components making up the columns of this matrix, it would appear to be an $n\times m$ matrix, which need not be square. However, as you have already observed in your question, we know that

$$
A(B\textbf{x}_i) = AB\textbf{x}_i = BA \textbf{x}_i = B(A\textbf{x}_i)\\
=B(\lambda \textbf{x}_i) = \lambda(B\textbf{x}_i)
$$

so $B\textbf{x}_i$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ or else is $0$. Or in other words $B$ takes eigenvectors of $A$ to new eigenvectors of $A$ with same eigenvalue or at worst to members of that eigenspace (the zero vector is in the eigenspace but is not considered an eigenvector). This is where the commutativity of $A$ and $B$ is invoked.

Hence each $B\textbf{x}_i$ is a linear combination of the eigenbasis vectors $\{\textbf{x}_j\}_j$, and may be therefore expressed as an $m$-component vector in terms of the basis $\mathcal{B}$, so this new matrix is actually square $m\times m$ when the column vectors are expressed in terms of that basis.

Therefore $B'$ has an eigenvalue $\mu$ (possibly complex) and also an eigenvector $\textbf{y}$. That is $B'\textbf{y}=\mu\textbf{y}$. This eigenvector of $B'$ (by construction) is also an eigenvector of $B$ (since $B'$ is a restriction of $B$) and of $A$, since

$$\textbf{y}=\sum a_i\textbf{x}_i\Rightarrow \\
\quad A\textbf{y}=A(\sum a_i\textbf{x}_i)=\sum a_iA\textbf{x}_i=\\
\sum a_i\lambda\textbf{x}_i=\lambda(\sum a_i\textbf{x}_i)=\lambda\textbf{y}.$$

Therefore $\textbf{y}$ is an eigenvector of both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: How does it say that an eigenvector of $B'$ is also an eigenvector of $B$?

Comment: @SoorajS $B'$ is just the restriction of $B$, so any eigenvector of $B'$ is also an eigenvector of $B$. Just like finding a solution for $\cos x=0$ in the domain $[0,2\pi]$ also gives you a root for $\cos x$ on the whole real line

Comment: I think I get it. $B'=X^{-1}BX$. Let $y$ be an eigenvector in the basis $X=\{x_i\}$ with eigenvalue $\mu$, ie., $B'y=\mu y\implies X^{-1}BXy=\mu y\implies BXy=\mu Xy$, where $y'=Xy$ is the same eigenvector in the standard basis. So $y$ the eigenvector of $B'$ and $y'$ the eigenvector of $B$ are the same vector, its just that they are represented in different basis, right ?

Comment: @SoorajS yes, that's right