# Show all $n\times n$ matrices which $AB=BA$ have a common eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $S$ is the set of all complex $n \times n$ matrices and for any two arbitrary $A$ and $B$ in $S$ we have $AB=BA$ then all matrices in $S$ have a common eigenvector.

I can show the result for two digonalizable matrix. But I don't know how to show that for all matrices in $S$. Also there is no condition of being digonalizable in this question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The matrices here aren't assumed to be diagonalisable, so I don't think that that answer applies.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147370/if-a-and-b-commute-show-that-they-have-a-common-eigenvector) (same proof as in the other duplicate, but they really call the common eigenvector $y$). Do you agree?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Yes, that seems more appropriate.